# Disable swipe on some fragments in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, touch-event

I have a `ViewPager` that can disable or enable swipe touches:

```
public class ConfigurablePager extends ViewPager {

    private final AtomicBoolean touchesAllowed = new AtomicBoolean();

    ...

    private boolean touchesAllowed() {
        return touchesAllowed.get();
    }

    public void enableTouches() {
        touchesAllowed.set(true);
    }

    public void disableTouches() {
        touchesAllowed.set(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return touchesAllowed() && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return touchesAllowed() && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Some fragments can be swiped but other can't. Pager adapter aware of swipe behaviour for each fragment. This behaviour can be changed in `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (adapter.isTouchesAllowed(position)) {
        views.pager.enableTouches();
    } else {
        views.pager.disableTouches();
    }
}
```

**The problem**

Sometimes, when I swipe fragments very fast and click on tab for other fragment simultaneously viewpager can throw `IllegalArgumentException`:

> FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
>       at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
>       at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1979)
>       at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
>       at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:110)
>       at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:462)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2080)
>       at com.test.debugpager.ConfigurablePager.onTouchEvent(ConfigurablePager.java:39)
>       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2203)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1938)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2231)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)

It's happend because `ViewPager` save last pointerId and get inconsistent state (some touch events dropped by `onInterceptTouchEvent`) e.g. `ACTION_MOVE` with incorrect `mActivePointerId` from last touch event (see sources of ViewPager.java)

**The question**

Is it posible to disable swipe on some fragments in other way, maybe without overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent`?

*ViewPager sources (onTouchEvent):*

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (!mIsBeingDragged) {
        final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);
        final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
        final float xDiff = Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
        final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);
        final float yDiff = Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Moved x to " + x + "," + y + " diff=" + xDiff + "," + yDiff);
        if (xDiff > mTouchSlop && xDiff > yDiff) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Starting drag!");
            mIsBeingDragged = true;
            requestParentDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            mLastMotionX = x - mInitialMotionX > 0 ? mInitialMotionX + mTouchSlop :
            mInitialMotionX - mTouchSlop;
            mLastMotionY = y;
            setScrollState(SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
            setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);

            // Disallow Parent Intercept, just in case
            ViewParent parent = getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

I've read intently [android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) about gesture recognizing in a `ViewGroup` and analyzed `ViewPager` `onTouchEvent` sources. Here I recognize that `ViewPager` do swipe only for `ACTION_MOVE` event so we shouldn't call touch callbacks only for this action and we should obey base `ViewGroup` `onInterceptTouchEvent` result before calling base class `onTouchEvent`.

According to this rules I changed my `ViewPager` code:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (touchesAllowed()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // ignore move action
        } else {
            if (super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)) {
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (touchesAllowed()) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev) != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: @toddsalpen it should work. When you say that something is not working, you have to provide some cases and environment where this solution doesn't work for you. Without that this comment is useless.